# Feynman Propagator for fermionic field $S_F(x-x)=0$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, quantum-electrodynamics, fermions, propagator

When doing some calculations in my QED course, my tutor used that for

$$S_F(x-y)= - \int \frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{i( \gamma_{\mu}p^{\mu}+m)}{p^2-m^2+i\epsilon}e^{-ip(x-y)}$$

the Feynman Propagator of a fermionic field, 
$$S_F(x-x) =0.$$

He shortly mentioned some symmetry argument (odd function over a symmetric interval?) but I didn't really get what he meant. I would be very grateful for some explanation here!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. There are lots of possible symmetry aspects, but do you mean in respect of the derivation of the propagator or it's application? I think you need to give more detail.

Comment: Hi, no the derivation is pretty clear. Like i mentioned, we used S(x-x) =0 in a other calculation and my tutoe mentionded that is it "obvious" that this is true because of some symmetry argument. But unfortunately i dont see why it obviously vanishes

Comment: Did your tutor mean the massless limit?

Comment: I don't think so. We were working on electron self energy and calculating the exact electron propagator up to second order in e. We used the above argument to get $Tr[S_{F }(0) \gamma^{\mu}] = 0$. Maybe just the trace expression is true?

Answer (score 3):

This is not true. See section 3 of [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.1261) where the full analytic expression is derived. For finite mass, we can write the $x^2\rightarrow 0^+$ fermionic propagator (the $x^2\rightarrow 0^-$ limit gives the same answer, but with Bessel instead of Hankel functions when $x^2\neq 0$):

$$
\begin{align}
S_F(x)&=(i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}+m)G_F(x)\\
&=-\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\left(\frac{-2i\gamma^{\mu}x_\mu}{(x^2)^2}+\frac{m}{x^2}\right)
\end{align}$$

Notice that the above expression diverges (i.e. it does not approach zero) in both of the following related limits:

1. $x^{\mu}\rightarrow 0 \,\,\,\implies x^2\rightarrow 0$
2. $x^2\rightarrow 0$ (but not necessarily $x^{\mu}\rightarrow 0$)

Comment: First of all thanks for the explaination, I couldn find any paper or book mentioning this at all! IS there then another way to prove that $Tr[S_{F}(0)\gamma^{\mu}]=0$ without assuming $S_{F}(0)=0$?

Comment: Is it true that $D_{F}(0) = 0$ for the scalar Feynman Propagator? ( $D_F(x-y)= \int \frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{i}{p^2-m^2+i\epsilon}e^{-ip(x-y)}$ Someone mentionend the following argument: Do a Wick rotation and use spherical coordinates to obtain 
$D(0) \sim \int d p_{E} \frac{p_{E}^{3}}{p_{E}^{2}-m^2} $
which then should be zero (PV) by integrating an odd function of $p$ over an symmetric intervall. But I'm not 100% convinced by that argument.

Comment: @Ramsey From the formula above, you can see that $\lim \textrm{Tr}\left[S_F(x)\gamma^{\mu}\right]_{x^{\mu}\rightarrow0}\neq 0$. Also, for $x^2\approx 0$, $$D_F(x)\approx \frac{-1}{4\pi^2x^2}$$

Comment: @Ramsey The argument you gave is wrong, because the integral you gave is indeterminate! If you split the integral into angular and radial integrals, you will get $0\times\infty$, which tells you that you need to be more careful in analyzing it for $x-y=0$. Therefore you need to evaluate it for finite $(x-y)^2$, and slowly take the limit $(x-y)^2\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I way already worrying that these argument are too handwaving - nevertheless I at least thought that the result was true. This totally screws up our discusssion of the electron self energy. Which is surprising because we got a seemingly right result in the end

Comment: @Ramsey In the discussion of the electron self-energy, you come across similarly divergent integrals, but they don't involve the $e^{ik(x-y)}$ factors (they come from "self-energy graphs"). There, however, you sometimes regularize the whole theory with a UV-cutoff, in which case when you split your momentum integral into angular and radial parts, you get $0\times \textrm{(const.)}=0$, i.e. the radial part is finite. You can get a similarly convergent answer in dimensional regularization. The final renormalized result though is the same no matter which regularization procedure you choose.